# Gray level slicing using OpenCv

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

I am developing an application in C# to transform COLOR image into gray level image slicing. I have used the following code to convert colour image to gray scale.

```
public void grayscale()
    {
        gray = Cv.CreateImage(src.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1);
        Cv.CvtColor(src, gray, ColorConversion.RgbToGray);
        Cv.SaveImage("3.jpg", gray);
    }
```

Now the problem is i want to determine the pixel value and set it to 0 or 255. I don't know how to get the pixel value of the gray scale image.
Can you please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In opecv c++ there's get2D function that returns the color. I assume that c# has something similar.

Anyway, it may be easier to get the same result using one or more threshold() and maybe boolean operations (and,or,not)